# Cannot access elements of struct mosquitto at Mosquitto MQTT Broker plugin

Tags: c++, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm implementing a plugin for the mosquitto MQTT broker (version 1.5) and I'm struggling at accessing some elements of the pointer to the struct of mosquitto client inside of my plugin implementation:

```
#include <mosquitto_plugin.h>
...
int mosquitto_auth_acl_check(void *userdata, int access, const struct mosquitto *client, const struct mosquitto_acl_msg *msg)
{
     const char *clientid = client->id;
     const char *username = client->username;
     ...
}
```

At compile time I retrieve the error:

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>     const char *clientid = client->id;

Can anybody give me some advice how to access the client data?

**Edit:** struct mosquitto is defined inside of the mosquitto source code (mosquitto_internal.h):

```
struct mosquitto {
      ...
      char *id;
      char *username;
      ...
 }
```

But mosquitto_internal.h is just for internal usage at mosquitto and cannot be accessed by my plugin (At least I think so...)

Inside of mosquitto_plugin.h (which is provided by the mosquitto and included by my plugin) there is just a "reference" to the mosquitto struct:

```
struct mosquitto;
```

Thus, as long as I'm not accessing any data of the mosquitto struct it compiles successfully, but if I try to access some data like the id it crashes.

Comment: The type `mosquitto` is not defined at this point. Please provide a [MCVE], so we can give proper help.

Comment: I believe your inability to access members of that struct is intentional -- the designers of the API don't want you to access them, because if you do, your code will break if/when they decide to change the contents of that struct in a future release.  (the fact that the struct is defined inside a header file with the string "internal" in its filename is a strong hint that you should not be using any of the contents of that file directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the accessor functions provided in `mosquitto_broker.h`, e.g.

```
const char *mosquitto_client_id(const struct mosquitto *client);
```

Answer (score 0):

let download source code, include needed header file in your plugin implement and using this Makefile

> NAME      = mosquitto_auth_plugin_http
>
> MOSQUITTO = ./mosquitto-1.5.2
>
> INC       = -I. -I$(MOSQUITTO)/ -I$(MOSQUITTO)/lib -I$(MOSQUITTO)/src
>
> CFLAGS    = -Wall -Werror -fPIC
>
> DEBUG     = -DMQAP_DEBUG
>
> LIBS      = -lcurl
>
> all: $(NAME).so
>
> $(NAME).so: $(NAME).o
>     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -shared $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)
>
> %.o : %.c
>     $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG) $(INC) $< -o $@
>
> clean:
>     rm -f *.o *.so

Comment: Please don't do this, as noted the contents of that struct are considered internal to the broker and not yours to look at.